# Initialize JQuery Modal without it opening a blank modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I was having to click my button twice for the modal to appear.  So I am trying to initialize it using `var modalObj = ..` as below.  But what is happening, is when I click a blank modal opens.

If I try to initialize the modal inside the `click` function I still have to click twice for the modal to open.  I know it just needs to be initialized somewhere first, but how can I initialize it without is opening an empty modal? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var modalObj = $('.confirm_modal').courses_modal_box();
    $("#confirm").click(function() {
        if (v_changeInd === 'N') {
            $('.confirm_modal').courses_modal_box({
                description: '<p>You have already submitted a request for a preferred first name of: ' + v_oldPFN +
                    ' Please wait for the request to be completed (within 2 business days)</p>' +
                    '<br><br>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center;">' +
                    '<input type="button" value="Okay" class="courses_modal_close">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '',
                width: '600',
                height: '300'
            });//Second modal
```

---

```
(function($){

// Defining our jQuery plugin

$.fn.courses_modal_box = function(prop){

    // Default parameters

    var options = $.extend({
        height : "300",
        width : "600",
        title:" Preferred First Name",
        description: "Preferred First Name",
        top: "50%",
        left: "50%"
    },prop);

    return this.click(function(e){
        add_block_page();
        add_popup_box();
        add_styles();
        $('.courses_modal_box').fadeIn();
    });

     function add_styles(){
        $('.courses_modal_box').css({

            'width':'600px',
            'height':'300px',
            'position': 'absolute',       //Keep as absolute
            //'top': '50%',
            //'left': '50%',              
            //'top': '400px',
            //'left': '500px',
            'top': '400',
            'right': '400',
            'bottom': '400',
            'left': '400',
            //'display':'center',
            'border':'1px solid #000000',
            'box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            'background': '#f2f2f2',
            'vertical-align': 'center',
            '-moz-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            '-webkit-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            '-ms-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            'border-radius':'10px',
            '-border-radius':'10px',
            '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
            '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',
            'z-index':'50'
        });


        $('.courses_modal_close').css({
            'position':'relative',
            'top':'-45px',
            'left':'20px',
            'float':'center',       
            'display':'block',
            'text-align':'center',  //Things I adjusted for the okay button on my modal.
            'height':'50px',
            'width':'100px',
            'vertical-align': 'middle',
        //  'border':'2px solid #000000',
            'margin':'0 auto'       //Centers the button in fireFox
        });
                    /*Block page overlay*/
        var pageHeight = $(document).height();
        var pageWidth = $(window).width();

        $('.courses_block_page').css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'top':'0',
            'left':'0',
            //'background-color':'rgba(0,0,8,0.5)',
            'height':pageHeight,
            'width':pageWidth,
            'z-index':'10'
        });
        $('.courses_inner_modal_box').css({
            'position':'initial',  
            'background-color':'#FFF',
            'height':(options.height - 70) + 'px',   
            'width':(options.width - 60) + 'px',
        //  'padding':'10px',
       //   'margin-bottom':'-50px',
            'margin':'1px',

            'border-radius':'10px',          //working in fireFox
            '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',  //chrome
            '-border-radius':'10px',         //IE
            'vertical-align': 'middle',
            'text-align': 'center'
        }); }

     function add_block_page(){
        var block_page = $('<div class="courses_block_page"></div>');

        $(block_page).appendTo('body');
       }

     function add_popup_box(){
         var pop_up = $('<div class="courses_modal_box"><a href="#" class="courses_modal_close"></a><div style="vertical-align:middle;" class="courses_inner_modal_box"><h2>'
                        + options.title + '</h2><p>' + options.description + '</p></div></div>').css({height:"300px"});
         $(pop_up).appendTo('.courses_block_page');

         $('.courses_modal_close').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
            $('.courses_block_page').fadeOut().remove();
         });
    }
    return this;
};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: What is the `courses_modal_box()` method?

Comment: That is my modal plugin.  Maybe the problem is in my plugin.  I will take a look.  I could past a copy of the code?

Comment: Can you include the code in that please, so we can see what plugin you use, and how you instantiate your modals.

Comment: This is how I instaniate var modalObj = $('.confirm_modal').courses_modal_box();

Comment: HTML <input type="submit" value="I confirm my preferred first name is correct and wish to proceed"  class = "confirm_modal"  data-toggle = "modal"  data-target = "#courses_modal_box"  id="confirm" style="width:600px </input>